# pandas: force 'minute' and 'seconds' to be zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one column: line1 [ 'daytime' ]

the format of this column looks like:

```
2018-02-07 17:40:29
2018-02-07 17:41:15
2018-02-07 17:41:55
2018-02-07 17:42:54
2018-02-07 17:43:44
2018-02-07 18:02:54
2018-02-07 18:03:44
Name: daytime, Length: 174859, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want to get:

```
2018-02-07 17:00:00
2018-02-07 17:00:00
2018-02-07 17:00:00
2018-02-07 17:00:00
2018-02-07 17:00:00
2018-02-07 18:00:00
2018-02-07 18:00:00
```

I want change the whole column

Comment: can you give a sample of expected output?

Comment: @arilwan I modified my question, is it clear enough?

Comment: Can you please post the code you used to produce the dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `floor` method of `pandas` Timestamps for doing just this.  Where `x` is an array (or column of a DataFrame):

```
x = pd.to_datetime(x).dt.floor('H')
```

[For `Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) or [for single timestamps](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html).

Comment: hey, I have a new question about pandas, could you help me? this is the link:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699951/pandas-replace-one-cells-value-from-mutiple-row-by-one-particular-row-based-on) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Use `astype` to cast to a numpy with unit as hour

```
df.daytime.astype('datetime64[h]')

#                 dates
# 0 2018-02-07 17:00:00
# 1 2018-02-07 17:00:00
# 2 2018-02-07 17:00:00
# 3 2018-02-07 17:00:00
# 4 2018-02-07 17:00:00
# 5 2018-02-07 18:00:00
# 6 2018-02-07 18:00:00
```

Some speed comparisons between the solutions provided:

```
datetime = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', freq='200S', periods=100)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(daytime=datetime))

%%timeit
df.daytime.dt.to_period('H')
# 826 µs ± 355 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
x = df.daytime.dt.floor('H')
# 774 µs ± 247 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
df.daytime.astype('datetime64[h]')
# 190 µs ± 12.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

With 1k records:

```
datetime = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', freq='200S', periods=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(daytime=datetime))

%%timeit
df.daytime.dt.to_period('H')
# 991 µs ± 312 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
x = df.daytime.dt.floor('H')
# 825 µs ± 203 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
df.daytime.astype('datetime64[h]')
# 237 µs ± 8.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: for the answers using `floor`, you don't need to use `pd.to_datetime()` ( `df.daytime` is already datetime).  On my machine, testing instead `df.daytime.dt.floor('H')` (a fairer comparison?) is slightly faster than using `to_period`.  But still not quicker than your answer : )

Comment: Hey @Tom you are right, I wanted to copy the exact same answer provided, but true, to keep the competition fair, better to leave it without the additional `pd.to_datetime()`

Comment: hey, I have a new question about pandas, could you help me? this is the link:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699951/pandas-replace-one-cells-value-from-mutiple-row-by-one-particular-row-based-on) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

#### For a unique Timestamp :

You can use replace :

```py
pd.Timestamp('2018-02-07 17:40:29').replace(minute=0, second=0)
```

This will output :

```py
Timestamp('2018-02-07 17:00:00')
```

#### For a `pd.Series`:

```py
df['your_column'].dt.to_period('H')
```

```py
    your_column
0   2018-02-07 17:00
1   2018-02-07 17:00
2   2018-02-07 17:00
3   2018-02-07 17:00
4   2018-02-07 17:00
```

Comment: how could I change the whole column?

Comment: Check my edit, this is probably what you're looking for :)

Comment: hey, I have a new question about pandas, could you help me? this is the link:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699951/pandas-replace-one-cells-value-from-mutiple-row-by-one-particular-row-based-on) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the module `re`:

```
import re

date = "2018-02-07 17:40:29"

print(re.sub('(?<=\d\d:)\d\d:\d\d', '00:00',date))
```

Output:

```
2018-02-07 17:00:00
```

Apply this to each element of the column using a for loop or a list comprehension.

Comment: hey, I have a new question about pandas, could you help me? this is the link:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699951/pandas-replace-one-cells-value-from-mutiple-row-by-one-particular-row-based-on) Thank you very much!