# pandas: replace one cell's value from mutiple row by one particular row based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my aim:

```
     uniqueIdentity    beginTime    progrNumber
0   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29    1
1   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29    2
2   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29    3
3   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29    4
4   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29    5
5   2018-02-07-5555333  17:48:29    2
6   2018-02-07-5555333  17:48:29    3
7   2018-02-07-5555333  17:48:29    4
8   2018-02-07-2345622  18:40:29    1
9   2018-02-07-2345622  18:40:29    2
10  2018-02-07-2345622  18:40:29    3
11  2018-02-07-2345622  18:40:29    4
```

my dataset now:

```
     uniqueIdentity    beginTime    progrNumber
0   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29    1
1   2018-02-07-6253554  17:41:15    2
2   2018-02-07-6253554  17:41:55    3
3   2018-02-07-6253554  17:42:54    4
4   2018-02-07-6253554  17:43:29    5
5   2018-02-07-5555333  17:49:15    2
6   2018-02-07-5555333  17:49:55    3
7   2018-02-07-5555333  17:50:54    4
8   2018-02-07-2345622  18:40:29    1
9   2018-02-07-2345622  18:41:15    2
10  2018-02-07-2345622  18:41:55    3
11  2018-02-07-2345622  18:42:54    4
```

That means:
**for rows having same 'uniqueIdentity', the 'beginTime' should be replaced by the value of cell which having the same'uniqueIdentity' and 'progrNumber' is the min 'progrNumber'.**

Comment: Is your `progrNumber` always ordered for each `uniqueIdentity` ?

Comment: Thanks hugolmn. for the number of uniqueIdentity is 4594 and the number of progrNumber == 1 is 4432. so for some 'uniqueIdentity', they are not begin with "1".

Comment: IIUC beginTime will always be minimal for the min progrNumber ?

Comment: yes! I tried ``` line.loc[line.uniqueIdentity == i, 'beginTime'] = tempDF[tempDF['progrNumber']==min(tempDF.progrNumber.unique())].iloc[0]['beginTime']``` it  gives me 4594 different 'uniqueIdentity' with 3554 different 'begintime'. There is too many rows I am not sure if it is a correct result or not..

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in the comments, the lowest `progrNumber` will also be the lowest `beginTime`. This means you can just take the lowest `beginTime` per `uniqueIdentity` using `groupby` and `transform`.

Note if `beginTime` is of type string, this will only work if it has consistent formatting. (e.g. '09:40:20' instead of '9:40:20')

```
df['beginTime'] = df.groupby('uniqueIdentity').beginTime.transform('min')

        uniqueIdentity beginTime progrNumber
0   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29           1
1   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29           2
2   2018-02-07-5555333  17:48:29           3
3   2018-02-07-5555333  17:48:29           4
4   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29           3
5   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29           4
6   2018-02-07-5555333  17:48:29           1
7   2018-02-07-5555333  17:48:29           2
8   2018-02-07-2345622  18:40:29           1
9   2018-02-07-2345622  18:40:29           3
10  2018-02-07-2345622  18:40:29           4
```

Comment: The question asks for the minimum `progrNumber` so this answer may not work.

Comment: The question was edited, the original question specified progrNumber == 1

Comment: Adjusted answer based on adjusted question.

Comment: There we go ! I don't think there is a better way to solve the problem, good job!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using a left join and some renaming

```
    # find rows where progrNumber is 1 
    df_prog1=df[df.progrNumber==1]
    # do a left join on the original 
    df=df.merge(df_prog1,on='uniqueIdentity',how='left',suffixes=('','_y'))
    # keep only the beginTime from the right frame 
    df=df[['uniqueIdentity','beginTime_y','progrNumber']]
    # rename columns
    df=df.rename(columns={'beginTime_y':'beginTime'})
    print(df)
```

Results in :

```
        uniqueIdentity beginTime  progrNumber
0   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29            1
1   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29            2
2   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29            3
3   2018-02-07-6253554  17:40:29            4
4   2018-02-07-5555333  17:48:29            1
5   2018-02-07-5555333  17:48:29            2
6   2018-02-07-5555333  17:48:29            3
7   2018-02-07-5555333  17:48:29            4
8   2018-02-07-2345622  18:40:29            1
9   2018-02-07-2345622  18:40:29            2
10  2018-02-07-2345622  18:40:29            3
11  2018-02-07-2345622  18:40:29            4
```

**if you're not sure** which record within a `uniqueIdentity` will have the minimum time, you can use a `groupby` instead of selecting where `progrNumber==1`:

```
    df_prog1=df.groupby('uniqueIdentity')['beginTime'].min().reset_index()
```

And do the left join as above.

Answer (score 0):

If the first `beginTime` for each user will *always* correspond to the minimum program number for each user, you can do:

```
d = df.groupby('uniqueIdentity')['beginTime'].first().to_dict()
df['beginTime'] = df['uniqueIdentity'].map(d)
```

To be more explicit about getting the time where the program number is minimum (regardless of its position), you replace `d` in the above with:

```
d = df.groupby('uniqueIdentity').apply(lambda x: x['beginTime'][x['progrNumber'].idxmin()]).to_dict()
```

These two yield the same result for your example data, but they will differ if there are users where the first `beginTime` (or minimum `beginTime` per Hugolmn) does not correspond to the minimum `progrNumber` for the user

Comment: The issue I see is that progrNumber is not ordered (see comments on the question), so using `first()` may lead to a wrong answer.

Comment: @Hugolmn Yes you are right, I addressed this in my second piece of code but I added some explanation to be clearer (hopefully).  But even if the progrNumber don't begin with `1`for each user, they may still be ascending anyway?

Answer (score 0):

### Using `groupby` and `map`

The hypothesis is that `beginTime` will always be minimal for a minimal `progrNumber`. This condition is true based on the question's comments.

In this answer, I collect the minimum beginTime of each `uniqueIdentity`and then map it to the original DataFrame based on `uniqueIdentity`.

```py
times = df.groupby('uniqueIdentity').beginTime.min()
df['beginTime'] = df.uniqueIdentity.map(times)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we cannot assume that the min `progrNumber` is also the min `beginTime`, a more sophisiticated approach is required:

```
df['beginTime'] = (
     df.groupby('uniqueIdentity', as_index=False, group_keys=False)
       .apply(lambda s: pd.Series(s[s.progrNumber==s.progrNumber.min()]
              .beginTime.item(), index=s.index)
       )
)

df
#    uniqueIdentity beginTime   progrNumber
# 0  2018-02-07-6253554 17:40:29    1
# 1  2018-02-07-6253554 17:40:29    2
# 2  2018-02-07-6253554 17:40:29    3
# 3  2018-02-07-6253554 17:40:29    4
# 4  2018-02-07-6253554 17:40:29    5
# 5  2018-02-07-5555333 17:49:15    2
# 6  2018-02-07-5555333 17:49:15    3
# 7  2018-02-07-5555333 17:49:15    4
# 8  2018-02-07-2345622 18:40:29    1
# 9  2018-02-07-2345622 18:40:29    2
# 10 2018-02-07-2345622 18:40:29    3
# 11 2018-02-07-2345622 18:40:29    4
```

If you don't want a oneliner, an approach with `map` would be ideal

```
mapping  = (
     df.groupby('uniqueIdentity')
       .apply(lambda s: s[s.progrNumber==s.progrNumber.min()].beginTime.iloc[0])
 )

 df['beingTime'] = df.uniqueIdentity.map(mapping)
```

**note:** You can replace the `iloc[0]` by `item()` if you guarantee that only one value has the min `progrNumber`